# Height of water in vessel containing gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

The question reads-

> Thin walled Cylinder of height h, mass m and cross section A filled with gas and floats on water. Now due to leakage depth of submergence increases by $\Delta h$. $P_o$ is the atmospheric pressure. We need initial pressure (say $P_1$)

Now I have the Idea of how to solve it but I just needed to check whether my calculated height of water sinked in is correct. Here's what I did -
Initial Submergence is $x$ now say due to leakage water comes in and fills by $y$ so now length of vessel inside water is $x + \Delta h - y$.

$\rho g V$ is the buoyant force

Density of water is $\rho$ so $$\rho g x A =mg$$
and then after water seeping in $$\rho g (x + \Delta h - y)A = mg + \rho gxA$$

Here's a diagram [image]

After solving which it gives $y= \frac{\Delta h}{2}$ But the book tells me it should be $y = \Delta h$. Is my solution correct?

Comment: See [Check my work](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) especially the second comment to the top answer (currently)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Is there any way I might edit my question to make it off hold?

Comment: I would draw a diagram before and after seepage, explain what each of each of the terms in the equations represents, e.g. what do $\rho g x A$ and $mg$ each represent and why should they be added, what principles are you applying?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Is it OK now?